# Problem with warnings after compiling assets

Tags: laravel, npm, sass, assets

When I compile assets with command npm run prod, I'm receiving this message:

> WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings
>
> warning  in ./resources/sass/app.scss
>
> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
> Warning
>
> (1973:3) Error in parsing SVG: Non-whitespace before first tag. Line:
> 0 Column: 1 Char: d
>
> @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253
>
> warning  in ./resources/sass/app.scss
>
> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
> Warning
>
> (2084:3) Error in parsing SVG: Non-whitespace before first tag. Line:
> 0 Column: 1 Char: d
>
> @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253

after this warning I get list of compiled files, and after that the warnings again. This time they seems to be more precise:

> WARNING in ./resources/sass/app.scss
> (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.scss)
> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
> Warning
>
> (1973:3) Error in parsing SVG: Non-whitespace before first tag. Line:
> 0 Column: 1 Char: d  @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253
>
> WARNING in ./resources/sass/app.scss
> (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.scss)
> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
> Warning
>
> (2084:3) Error in parsing SVG: Non-whitespace before first tag. Line:
> 0 Column: 1 Char: d  @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253

When I compile assets with "npm run dev" there is no warnings after process.

Anyone have idea what's causing this behavior ?

app.scss content:

```
@use 'sass:math';
@use 'sass:list';

@import "compile/bootstrap";
@import "compile/bootstrap_limitless";
@import "compile/layout";
@import "compile/components";
@import "compile/colors";

@import "datatables";
@import "forms";
@import "daterangepicker";
```

Comment: These warnings are saying that you have a non-whitespace character at the start of your `app.scss` file, and you shouldn't? Generally, first character of a `.scss` file is likely `@import()`, or an identifier `#element { ... }` or class, like `.element { ... }`, or an HTML tag like `div { ... }` etc. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74433626/edit) to include this file, or, since these are just warnings, you can probably safely ignore them.

Comment: I've added content of app.scss file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. SVGO package from Cssnano was the problem.
To fix this just add to mix.options (in webpack.mix.js file) following lines:

```
mix.options({
   cssNano: {
      svgo: false
   }
});
```

That's all.